# Handlebars exphbs is not a function

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Error is "app.engine("handlebars", exphbs());  'TypeError: exphbs is not a function
at Object. '"

```
const express = require('express')
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.engine("handlebars", exphbs());
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exphbs` isn't a function, it is an object of stuff exported by handlebars (see the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars)). The function you want to use is `exphbs.engine()` like this:

```
app.engine("handlebars", exphbs.engine());
```

Alternatively, you can destructure the object and take out `engine` directly:

```
const express = require('express')
const { engine } = require("express-handlebars");
const path = require("path");
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.engine("handlebars", engine());
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
```

Comment: @chesterThapa Always happy to help! You can mark my answer as correct (the checkmark) to indicate to others that my answer solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think its possible that the exphbs function is not properly installed or imported:

```
  npm install express-handlebars
```

Import it with:

```
  const exphbs  = require('express-handlebars');
```

If that's not the case, and you have it installed and imported correctly. Then see if updating to the latest version fixes the issue:

```
  npm update express-handlebars
```

EDIT: Now that I think about it, you need to call the engine() function on exphbs to get the actual function that you can use to register the handlebars templating engine with your Express app.

The correct code should be:

```
  const express = require('express')
  const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
  const path = require("path");
  const app = express()
  const port = 3000

  app.engine("handlebars", exphbs.engine());
  app.set("view engine", "handlebars");
```

Comment: I had already tried this but it doesn't work

Comment: I think Michael's comment above is your best bet.